# Returning all field from Datatable to AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My problem is, it doesn't display table from c# after I input text and click search button. I have tried many ways, but it can't work. Below is my code.

Below is my javascript:

```
url: "/Testing/TraceReport/traceReport.aspx/app",
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',    
success: function (response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var EquipmentList = xml.find("Table1");
    var content = "";
    if (EquipmentList.length > 0) {
        $(EquipmentList).each(function () {
            content += "<tr align='center'>";

            if ($(this).find('Column1').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column1').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            if ($(this).find('Column2').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column2').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            if ($(this).find('Column3').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column3').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            if ($(this).find('Column4').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column4').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            if ($(this).find('Column5').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column5').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            if ($(this).find('Column7').text() == "") { content += "<td><b><font color='red'>UNKNOWN</font></b></td>"; }
            else { content += "<td><b>" + $(this).find('Column7').text() + "</b></td>"; }

            content += "</tr>";
        });
    }
```

Below is my c#:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(table);

return ds.GetXml();
```

Comment: With all that code please explain what you are doing and what you want to achieve at the end.

Comment: I want display the table after click a button. The table is from dataset in backend to ajax.

Comment: Open up `Dev Tools` (F12) on your browser and check the console for any errors thrown.

Comment: It throw null object reference

Answer (score 0):

The `dataType` property tells the server what type of data to return.

You're telling the server you want to receive `json`.  Yet, it looks like the server is sending `xml`.  Update the `dataType` in the `ajax` method:

```
...
dataType: 'xml', 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I understand, You are returning the DataTable object itself from your `WebMethod` and you want to read all the returned `rows` from the `column`.

Here is my suggestion to do it, Make a model and copy your values from the `DataTable` to a C# class object Generic List. Below is the idea:

```
// Sample Class
public class MyData
{
    public string Column1 {get; set;}
    public string Column2 {get; set;}
    public string Column3 {get; set;}
    public string Column4 {get; set;}
    // ... and so on
}
```

Then in your `WebMethod`:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]  // To Force the service method to return JSON only
public static List<MyData> DoStuff()
{
    DataTable table = FetchMyTable(); // method that gets your data from SQL
    List<MyData> data = new List<MyData>();
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        MyData dataItem = new MyData
        {
            Column1 = row["Column1"].ToString(),
            Column2 = row["Column2"].ToString(),
            // And So on...
        };
        data.Add(dataItem);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
// your other parameters
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){
        // Now from here you can loop through it
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
            var column1 = response[i].Column1;
            var column2 = response[i].Column2;
            // and so on....
        }
    }
});
```

This is a rough idea how to achieve the task you are doing. Hope it helps.

PS: I didn't used any compiler so the code is not tested, it may need some love.